# Test a local connection with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

Is there a way to **check if a cable is not unplugged** by using Qt ?

I know the `Ip adress` that I want to contact, at first I was thinking of doing a `ping request` on this `Ip Adress`, but it seems to be too much complicated for this simple task.

So I'm thinking that maybe, there is a simple function able to do this in `QNetwork library`.

I search on the Internet but all the solutions are not testing one particular IP.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if a cable is not unplugged by using Qt ?

You can achieve this for specified interface using `QNetworkSession`:

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager nwManager (this);
for (;;QThread::sleep (1) ) {
    bool isConfigurationFound {false};
    for (auto & configuration : nwManager.allConfigurations (/*QNetworkConfiguration::Active*/) ) {
        // Name depends on the environment: "Wired connection 1", "McDonaldsFreeWiFi", "Home", "eth0", "eth1", etc...
        if (isConfigurationFound = (configuration.name () == "eth0") ) {
            QNetworkSession session (configuration, this);
            session.open ();
            session.waitForOpened (/*timeout*/);

            qDebug () << "Session info:";
            qDebug () << "- usage: " << (session.isOpen () ? "Opened" : "Closed");
            qDebug () << "- state: " << (session.state  () == QNetworkSession::Connected ? "Connected" : "Not connected");

            break;
        }
    }
    qDebug () << (isConfigurationFound ? "" : "Configuration not found.");
}
```

If you launch this code with connected cable you get:

```
"Session info:" 
"- usage: Opened;" 
"- state: Connected;"
```

If you unplugged cable you get:

```
"Session info:" 
"- usage: Closed" 
"- state: Not connected"
```

**Here is full example** (also available at [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/tree/master/24864092)):

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.8)
project (NaQt)
find_package (Qt5Network)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set (NaQt_SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
set (NaQt_HEADERS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/NetworkAnalyzer.h)
qt5_wrap_cpp (NaQt_HEADERS_MOC ${NaQt_HEADERS})

add_executable (
    naqt
    ${NaQt_SOURCES}
    ${NaQt_HEADERS_MOC}
)
target_link_libraries (
    naqt
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Network
)
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QtCore>
#include "NetworkAnalyzer.h"

int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
    QCoreApplication application (argc, argv);
    NetworkAnalyzer networkAnalyzer (& application);
    return application.exec ();
}
```

`NetworkAnalyzer.h`

```
#ifndef QT_NETWORK_ANALYZER_H
#define QT_NETWORK_ANALYZER_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QNetworkSession>
#include <QDebug>

class NetworkAnalyzer : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    NetworkAnalyzer (QObject * parent = nullptr)
    {
        QNetworkConfigurationManager nwManager (this);
        for (;;QThread::sleep (1) ) {
            bool isConfigurationFound {false};
            for (auto & configuration : nwManager.allConfigurations (/*QNetworkConfiguration::Active*/) ) {
                // Name depends on the environment: "Wired connection 1", "McDonaldsFreeWiFi", "Home", "eth0", "eth1", etc...
                if (isConfigurationFound = (configuration.name () == "eth0") ) {
                    QNetworkSession session (configuration, this);
                    session.open ();
                    session.waitForOpened (/*timeout*/);

                    qDebug () << "Session info:";
                    qDebug () << "- usage: " << (session.isOpen () ? "Opened" : "Closed");
                    qDebug () << "- state: " << (session.state  () == QNetworkSession::Connected ? "Connected" : "Not connected");

                    break;
                }
            }
            qDebug () << (isConfigurationFound ? "" : "Configuration not found.");
        }
    }
};

#endif//QT_NETWORK_ANALYZER_H
```

Comment: This works, but I have 2 ethernet card on my computer and I want to know which one isn't connected, is there a way to get the Ip adress from session or something like that ?

Comment: `but I have 2 ethernet card on my computer and I want to know which one isn't connected` - for this purpose test connection for "eth0" and "eth1" interfaces. `is there a way to get the Ip adress from session or something like that?` - I'm interesting in this question too and unfortunately I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening a socket to the specified IP address on a predefined port :

```
QTcpSocket tester;

tester.connectToHost(address, port);

if(tester.waitForConnected(3000)) {
    //Remote host is online
} else {
    //Remote host is offline
}
```

Comment: How could I wait for connection, without freezing the whole program ?

Comment: Set a timer and wait for connected() signal from QTcpSocket.

Comment: Well to me it's still blocking, can you provide an example ?

Comment: @EvansBelloeil you can try QtConcurrent::Run for this needs

Answer (score 0):

Use QT's QNetworkAccessManager class which provides networkAccessibleChanged Signal
and connect a slot to it

```
connect(&networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(networkAccessibleChanged(QNetworkAccessManager::NetworkAccessibility)), this, SLOT(onNetworkAccessibilityChanged(QNetworkAccessManager::NetworkAccessibility)));
```

it emits signal telling when the ethernet cable is unplugged

Comment: The SLOT is not call,when i turn of wifi